# "no such type exists in the schema: 'timetz'" in hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

```
mutation MyMutation($title: String!, $date: date!,$stime: timetz!  , $etime: timetz!
 ) {
  insert_schedules(objects: {title: $title , date: $date, start_time: $stime, end_time:$etime}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}`
```

Error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.variableValues",
        "code": "validation-failed"
      },
      "message": "no such type exists in the schema: 'timetz'"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I am using timetz but it doesnt work.Even using time doesnt work.What to use.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `type` of `start_time` and/or `end_time` columns are not `timetz`.

> There are two solutions:

1. changing the type of those columns to timetz; can be achieved by running this sql as a migration

```
alter table schedules alter column start_time type timetz;
alter table schedules alter column end_time type timetz;
```

---

2. or if your column is of type timestamp with timezone, you can simply do:

```
mutation MyMutation($title: String!, $date: date!, $stime: timestamptz!, $etime: timestamptz!) {
  insert_schedules(objects: {title: $title, date: $date, start_time: $stime, end_time: $etime}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

Although both `timetz` and `timestamptz` are supported by hasura, `timestamptz` stores both date and time, with time zone, and is the more recommended one.
Check this page out to know more about their differences.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html